# springdoc-openapi-ui swagger 3 swagger-ui.html is throwing 302 and redirecting to some other page that doesn't exist

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

We migrated springfox to springdoc-openapi-ui and changed the configuration as mentioned in the documention.

Documentation - [Springfox to openAPI](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html) and swagger ui is served behind a proxy. For that added ForwardedHeaderFilter in the bean configuration.

pom.xml dependency,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to hit the swagger ui - https://somedomain/appName/swagger-ui.html, in the network tab we can see 302 as a response code and redirecting to some other page i.e index.html and throwing 404 that's page doesn't exist.

[image]

I followed this solution [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153074/springdoc-openapi-ui-does-not-honor-context-path-in-location) but didn't work.

Let me know what should be the cause and solution.

Comment: why we need to close this question ?